# Cech Cohomology and the Dold-Kan Correspondence

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff

Given a (co/contravariant) functor $F$ from the simplicial category $\Delta$ to an abelian category $A$, we can form its Cech complex (or "alternating face map complex" on [the nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Moore+complex)), i.e. $CF^n=F([n])$, and $\partial^n$ is $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^iF(\delta^n_i)$, where $\delta^n_i$ is the face map.

By the Dold-Kan correspondence, we can then reconstruct a (co)simplicial object $\Gamma CF$ which has this $CF^\bullet$ as its Moore complex. [In particular](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Moore+complex#normalization), its Cech complex is a direct sum of $CF^\bullet$ and a nullhomotopic complex, and is homotopy equivalent to $CF^\bullet$.

So my question is: can we say anything more direct about relationship between our $F$ and $\Gamma CF$ than "they have homotopy-equivalent Cech complexes"? More generally, what relation does homotopy equivalence impose on (co)simplicial objects?

Comment: If you have an open cover you can get a _simplicial_ object.

Comment: How? I see how you can get the face maps from the projections, but I don't see what the degeneracy maps would be.

Comment: The simplicial identities force them to be (generalised) diagonal embeddings. Use the universal property of projections.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was having an indexing issue that made me think there should be more degeneracy maps than diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, if anybody is still wondering, is [simplicial homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_homotopy).